# Want to fetch multiple values of same tag from XML in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I have the below xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SyncConsumer xmlns="http://www.ford.com/oagis" xmlns:oa="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" environment="Test" revision="1.7" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ford.com/oagis C:\VCC_Workspace\gca_D14.07\gca_xsd\src\main\resources\Consumer\Ford\BODs\SyncConsumer.xsd">
    <oa:ApplicationArea>
    <oa:Sender>
    <oa:LogicalId>Volvo</oa:LogicalId>
    <oa:Component>Vista</oa:Component>
    <oa:Task>SyncConsumer</oa:Task>
    <oa:AuthorizationId>MQTEST27</oa:AuthorizationId>
    </oa:Sender>
    <oa:CreationDateTime>2016-07-05T12:23:47Z</oa:CreationDateTime>
    <oa:BODId>mq-test-027</oa:BODId>
    </oa:ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
    <oa:Sync confirm="Always">
    <oa:SyncCriteria>
    <oa:SyncExpression action="Add"/>
    </oa:SyncCriteria>
    </oa:Sync>
    <Consumer>
    <ConsumerHeader>
    <ResponseTemplate Name="VistaSyncConsumer">
    </ResponseTemplate>
    <Source>AU</Source>
    </ConsumerHeader>
    <ConsumerDetails Category="Person">
    <PersonDetails>
           <FirstName>Test_data_027</FirstName>
               <Surname>testdata_027</Surname>
     <Gender>MM</Gender>
    </PersonDetails>
    <EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Home">no_email@volvocars.com</EmailAddress>
    <EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Home">no_email_1@volvocars.com</EmailAddress>
    <EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Home">no_email_2@volvocars.com</EmailAddress>
    <ContactNumber Active="true" Usage="Home">6666666</ContactNumber>
    <ContactNumber Active="true" Usage="Home">77777777</ContactNumber>
    <ContactNumber Active="true" Usage="Home">888888888</ContactNumber>
    </ConsumerDetails>
    </Consumer>
    </DataArea>
    </SyncConsumer>

the xml is stored as a clob in orig messsage in xml_message_table.
Now i want all the email address and contactno from the above xml.
```

And I tried the below code :

```
Select Contact_no.EmailAddress as EmailAddress
  , Contact_no.ContactNumber as ContactNumber
 from xml_message_335
    , xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.ford.com/oagis'),'SyncConsumer/DataArea/Consumer/ConsumerDetails'  
           passing xmltype(xml_message_335.orig_message)
           columns 
               EmailAddress  varchar2(30) path 'EmailAddress'
              ,ContactNumber  varchar2(30) path 'ContactNumber'
          ) Contact_no;
```

Context:
This query is running only when the xml have only one emailaddress and contactnumber. If the value exceeds, my query doesn't work.

I want all the value of email address and contactnumber with n number of occurrence in this xml.
Where it doesn't stuck on the values having more than one.

Comment: Yeah, that is going to be a problem.  Since you  have multiple elements for emailaddress and contactnumber, you cannot "flatten" that.  It is no different than having a parent table (SyncConsumer ) with multiple child tables.

Comment: What is the exact output you need from that input? Never mind about **how** you can get it; just think about **what** you need out of that XML, in the format of the output of a SQL query. You will see that even that question is really hard (in fact it doesn't have a logical answer, as OldProgrammer pointed out already). You have a client with multiple home email addresses and multiple phone numbers - you can't really have that in a single table (other than by violating First Normal Form: comma separated list of emails, comma separated list of phone numbers).

Comment: By the way, that is the real problem; if you just had multiple emails, and you wanted those extracted (along with the other information), one row per email, that would be easy, albeit repetitive. / With all that said, a possible solution is to have nested table columns for email and "contact number"; is that something you are considering? As a much better alternative to comma-separated lists?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want one row for each email or phone number, you can do something like this:

- Have two separate calls to `xmltable`; one to extract the phone numbers, the other the emails addresses
- Add a `for ordinality` column to each of these to assign row numbers to the extracted elements
- Join the output of these together on the ordinality columns.

I'm guessing that the number of email addresses & phone numbers could vary in each document and they won't always have an equal number (e.g 1 email & 2 phones or vice-versa).

So I've used a `full outer join` to combine these tables. If there will always be three or the same number of each, you could use an inner join instead.

Which looks like:

```
with rws as (
  select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncConsumer xmlns="http://www.ford.com/oagis" xmlns:oa="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" environment="Test" revision="1.7" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ford.com/oagis C:\VCC_Workspace\gca_D14.07\gca_xsd\src\main\resources\Consumer\Ford\BODs\SyncConsumer.xsd">
  <oa:ApplicationArea>
    <oa:Sender>
      <oa:LogicalId>Volvo</oa:LogicalId>
      <oa:Component>Vista</oa:Component>
      <oa:Task>SyncConsumer</oa:Task>
      <oa:AuthorizationId>MQTEST27</oa:AuthorizationId>
    </oa:Sender>
    <oa:CreationDateTime>2016-07-05T12:23:47Z</oa:CreationDateTime>
    <oa:BODId>mq-test-027</oa:BODId>
  </oa:ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <oa:Sync confirm="Always">
      <oa:SyncCriteria>
        <oa:SyncExpression action="Add" />
      </oa:SyncCriteria>
    </oa:Sync>
    <Consumer>
      <ConsumerHeader>
        <ResponseTemplate Name="VistaSyncConsumer" />
        <Source>AU</Source>
      </ConsumerHeader>
      <ConsumerDetails Category="Person">
        <PersonDetails>
          <FirstName>Test_data_027</FirstName>
          <Surname>testdata_027</Surname>
          <Gender>MM</Gender>
        </PersonDetails>
        <EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Home">no_email@volvocars.com</EmailAddress>
        <EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Home">no_email_1@volvocars.com</EmailAddress>
        <EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Home">no_email_2@volvocars.com</EmailAddress>
        <ContactNumber Active="true" Usage="Home">6666666</ContactNumber>
        <ContactNumber Active="true" Usage="Home">77777777</ContactNumber>
        <ContactNumber Active="true" Usage="Home">888888888</ContactNumber>
      </ConsumerDetails>
    </Consumer>
  </DataArea>
</SyncConsumer>' x from dual
), emails as (
  select x.*
  from   rws, 
    xmltable (
      xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.ford.com/oagis'),
      'SyncConsumer/DataArea/Consumer/ConsumerDetails/EmailAddress'  
         passing xmltype(rws.x)
         columns 
           seq for ordinality,
           email_address varchar2(320) path '.'
    ) x 
), phones as (
  select x.*
  from   rws, xmltable (
      xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.ford.com/oagis'),
      'SyncConsumer/DataArea/Consumer/ConsumerDetails/ContactNumber'  
         passing xmltype(rws.x)
         columns 
           seq for ordinality,
           contact_number varchar2(320) path '.'
    ) x
)
  select * 
  from   emails 
  full outer join phones
  using  ( seq ) ;
  
SEQ    EMAIL_ADDRESS               CONTACT_NUMBER   
     1 no_email@volvocars.com      6666666           
     2 no_email_1@volvocars.com    77777777          
     3 no_email_2@volvocars.com    888888888
```